# Excel Data validation with whole number and specific text

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I want to inquire if it is possible to combine two data validation options, particularly whole number (with min and max at 0 to 999) and a specific text, which is "n/a".

I know this isn't possible with the basic data validation button, and am thinking if this is possible with VBA.

I want participants to be able to enter a value between 0 to 999, which pertains to the days before their deadline. But I want another option, "n/a", to be available if in case the said item is not applicable for them.

Thanks!

Comment: yes it is, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of potential options.

As you suggest, VBA and regex type stuff would be an option.  However, it isn't a particularly good option, being very easy to break if someone turns off macros, deletes macros in the sheet, changes file formats etc... Furthermore VBA isn't giving you any significant advantage in speed, flexibility or debuggability.  I'd go with a different option.

Use data validation from a custom list.  Put the numbers 0-999 and "N/A" in a column (on a hidden sheet?), name that range `DeadlineValueList`, then open the Data tab > Data Validation > Allow: List > Choose List > enter "=DeadlineValueList" in the box.  Simple, effective, easy to debug and modify.

This will force the users to use a value in `DeadlineValueList`  and, as a bonus, provide said options in a drop down list for the target cell.

PS.  I would suggest having N/A at the top of your Data Validation list!

Comment: Thanks for this! What worried me with the custom list was actually that if they click the drop down button, it would be a pretty long list. However, I forgot that you could actually turn off the drop down button, so the participants could just manually enter the value or just "n/a", which is still in the list. Thanks once again!

Comment: Very welcome!  As an unasked-for tip, when not using a drop-down menu I'd suggest adding an "Input message" (a toggle option inside the data validation menu) or a cell comment that provides the users with the information about what is allowed in that cell.  The various case-sensitive options for `N\A` seem a likely source of confusion!